# is there any operation other than scan and query in DynamoDB?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Operation Query

```
 $params = [
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'ProjectionExpression' => '#yr, title, info.genres, info.actors[0]',
    'KeyConditionExpression' =>
        '#yr = :yyyy and title between :letter1 and :letter2',
    'ExpressionAttributeNames'=> [ '#yr' => 'year' ],
    'ExpressionAttributeValues'=> $eav
];
```

Scan Operation

```
$result = $dynamodb->scan($params);
```

is there any other operation to read..?

Comment: There is getItem. Not really sure what do you want to do? What's wrong with query and scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three primary operations to read data in DynamoDB:

1. getItem - fetches a single item by its primary key
2. query - fetches one or more items by specifying the partition key and optional parameters on the sort key.
3. scan - fetch one or more items by any attribute.

GetItem and query are the most performant operations available.  Scan is powerful but should be used with caution since it needs to inspect every item in the database to return results.